# Facebook Graph API Batch Requests - Retrieve Friends Likes returns unknown error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, batch-file, batch-processing

I'm accessing the Graph API using batch requests, while trying to retrieve all of my friends likes the plataform returns-me a unknow error. By the way i'm using JSONPath to retrieve the likes.

likes?ids={result=friends:$.data.*.id}

Is this an security related question or a bug?

Comment: When trying to retrive friends links, the same error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your access token has `friends_likes` by using the linter: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug